# BigQuery - DATE_TRUNC error

Tags: date, google-bigquery

trying to get the monthly aggregated data from Legacy table. Meaning date columns are strings:

```
amount  date_create
100     2018-01-05
200     2018-02-03
300     2018-01-22
```

However, the command

```
 Select DATE_TRUNC(DATE date_create, MONTH) as month, 
        sum(amount) as amount_m 
 from table  
 group by 1
```

Returns the following error:

> Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "date_create"

Why does this query not run and what can be done to avoid the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you meant to cast `date_create` instead of using the `DATE` keyword (which is how you construct a literal value) there. Try this instead:

```
Select DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date_create), MONTH) as month, 
    sum(amount) as amount_m 
from table
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: This one returns ```Error: No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: STRING. Supported signatures: DATE(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]); DATE(DATETIME); DATE(INT64, INT64, INT64)``` However, casting works: `date_trunc(cast(date_create as date), MONTH) as Month` works

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

`date_trunc(cast(date_create as date), MONTH) as Month`

Answer (score 1):

Another option for BigQuery Standard SQL - using [`PARSE_DATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date) function

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 100 amount, '2018-01-05' date_create UNION ALL
  SELECT 200, '2018-02-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 300, '2018-01-22' 
)
SELECT 
  DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', date_create), MONTH) AS month, 
  SUM(amount) AS amount_m 
FROM `project.dataset.table`  
GROUP BY 1
```

with result as

```sql
Row month       amount_m     
1   2018-01-01  400  
2   2018-02-01  200
```

In practice - I prefer PARSE_DATE over CAST as former kind of documents expectation about data format

Answer (score 0):

Try to add double quote to date_creat :

```
Select DATE_TRUNC('date_create', MONTH) as month, 
        sum(amount) as amount_m 
 from table  
 group by 1
```